# Should ASP.NET v2 IIS server extension be missing after .NET 4 is installed?

Tags: asp.net, wcf, iis-6

I'm having a ton of issues when my ASP.NET sites are using version 2. For example, all my SVC and ASPX files return "file not found". Also when I use IISMgr and navigate to:

ServerName
..... Web Service Extensions

I notice that ASP.NET v2 is not present. I tried aspnet_regiis but no luck. Does anyone have Windows 2003 with .NET 4 installed?  Can you tell me what you have for ASP.NET 4.x so I can manually re-add the IIS extension?

[image]

**UPDATE**

aspnet_regiis.exe – i seemed to now have worked.  But I'm still having issues with WCF.  I just tried reinstalling WCF using ServiceModelReg -i and I get this in the event log

[image]

Also, this is what ServiceModelReg -ls looks like (note no Web Host Script Mappings exist)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

A probable solution is [here](http://myitforum.com/cs2/blogs/yli628/archive/2008/05/01/asp-net-v2-0-50727-missing-from-web-services-extensions-in-iis-manager.aspx). Excerpt:

> > When you build Window 2003 R2 SP2
> >     server – by default it has
> >     Microsoft.NET Framework 2.0 Service
> >     Pack 1 and Microsoft .NET Framework
> >     3.0 Service Pack1 installed. You will notice ASP.NET v2.0.50727 is
> >     MIA(missing in action) in Web Services
> >     Extension in IIS manager. How you make
> >     it appear and make it as an “allowed”
> >     service?..start a DOS window – change to the following directory
>
> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727>
>   or
>   C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727>
>   for 64 bit
>
> Type aspnet_regiis.exe – i

**EDIT**: I just now read that you tried aspnet_regiis - did you use the correct Framework folder depending on your processor architecture?

Comment: Thanks!  I just ran aspnet_regiis -ir and that seemed to fix the issue.  Now I did an ServiceModelReg -lv for WCF support and is says no Windows Host Script Mappings are installed.  Any ideas?

Comment: Here is the command I used:
C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.0\Windows Communication Foundation>ServiceModelReg.exe -lv

Comment: Did you try the plain old ServiceModelReg -i ?